# Koin 3.2/Compose - injecting an activity-scoped viewmodel from a composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, koin

I have scoped a viewmodel to an activity like this:

```
    scope<MyActivity> {
      scoped<UseCase1> { UseCase1Impl(get()) }
      scoped<UseCase2> { UseCase2Impl(get()) }
      viewModel { parameters -> MyViewModel(parameters.get(), get(), get()) }
    }
```

In my activity I cannot access the viewmodel inside a composable with this call:

```
        setContent {

      val viewModel: MyViewModel by org.koin.androidx.compose.viewModel {
        ParametersHolder(mutableListOf("1"))
      }
      viewModel.doSomething() 
}
```

UNLESS I also do this outside the composable:

```
   private val viewModel by viewModel<CameraNameViewModel> { parametersOf("1") }

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel // If I comment this, it crashes

   // setContent etc
}
```

The error is

```
 Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: |- No definition found for class:'com.anonymised.path.to.MyViewModel'. Check your definitions!
```

Deep-diving with the debugger, it looks like the activities mViewmodelStore property is only populated when accessed outside the composable. I do have a workaround in that I can just inject every viewmodel in my top-level activity, but it doesn't seem right basically injecting it twice.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two options:

---

Option 1: If your both your activity and your composable need the viewModel:

- Inject your `viewModel` into your activity like you already have
- just pass the `viewModel` to your composable

  ```
  class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
      private val viewModel by viewModel<CameraNameViewModel> { parametersOf("1") }

      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

          setContent {
              YourComposeScreen(viewModel)
          }
      }
  }

  @Composable fun YourComposeScreen(viewModel: CameraNameViewModel){
      /*your composable */
  }
  ```

---

Option 2: you only need your viewModel in your composable:

- don't inject the viewModel into your composable
- just use [koins Compose-Syntax](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/compose) to inject the `viewModel` to your composable

  ```
  class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

          setContent {
              YourComposeScreen() // <- we do not need any parameter here
          }
      }
  }

  @Composable fun YourComposeScreen(
      viewModel: CameraNameViewModel = getViewModel(parameters = { parametersOf("1") })
  ){
      /*your composable */
  }
  ```

Comment: Option 2 is exactly what I'm trying to - my issue is that it crashes if I try and scope it to the activity, UNLESS I reference it in the activity first.